# Angular2 unsubscribe valueChanges on formGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue with unsubscribe values changes on form, which I use to live validation. My method which I want to turn off in precise case:

```
this.taskForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
                       ...
                this.output = data;
        });
```

I want to remove this listener after submit. How can I do this? I've tried to use `unsubscribe` but it doesn't help. Below is my try:

```
this.sub = this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
                          ...
                this.output = data;
        });
```

and I tried to add `this.sub.unsubscribe();`, but it didn't help.

```
onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    let context: number = 0;

    if(form.valid) {
        this.appService.addTask(form.value)
            .then(result => {
                this.lgModal.hide();
                this.taskCreate.reset({ priority: '' });
                this.cartBox.cart = [];
                this.cartBox.showCart = false;
                this.createTaskDone.emit();
                this.attachments.attachmentList = [];
                this.uploader.clearQueue();
                this.reloadContent.emit(context);   
                this.counter += 1;  
                console.log("COUNTER: ", this.counter);

            })} 
    else {
        this.formValidator(form);

    }

}

formValidator(form:FormGroup) {
    if(!form.controls['goal'].valid) this.formValid.goalErr = 1; else this.formValid.goalErr = 0;
    if(!form.controls['priority'].valid) this.formValid.priorityErr = 1; else this.formValid.priorityErr = 0;
    if(!form.controls['note'].valid) this.formValid.noteErr = 1; else this.formValid.noteErr = 0;

    this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
        this.formValidator(form);
        this.output = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem has to be somewhere else. `unsubscribe()` works this way. Can you please provide more context around the code you posed. Where and how is this code called?

Comment: Hi Gunter! I'v added more info in description. Precisely I call Validator when user wannt to submit invalid form. then This Validator runs valueChanges subscribent, which looks on all form fields and detect changes, and if field is invalid shows label with validation information.

on first run it is working ok, but tricky thing is, when I wannt to send next  form. In this case valueChanges works since form is opened, not when user want to send invalid form.

Comment: Nowhere in that code do you show either: 1. where you tried to `unsubscribe`; or 2. what precisely you mean by *"doesn't help"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribing to `valueChanges` inside `formValidator` seems wrong to me

```
formValidator(form:FormGroup) {
    if(!form.controls['goal'].valid) this.formValid.goalErr = 1; else this.formValid.goalErr = 0;
    if(!form.controls['priority'].valid) this.formValid.priorityErr = 1; else this.formValid.priorityErr = 0;
    if(!form.controls['note'].valid) this.formValid.noteErr = 1; else this.formValid.noteErr = 0;

    this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
        this.formValidator(form);
        this.output = data;
    });
}
```

I'd assume what you actually want is to move

```
this.sub = this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    this.formValidator(form);
    this.output = data;
});
```

just below the code that initializes `this.taskCreate` and then in `onSubmit` do the `this.sub.unsubscribe()` call.

I assume your problem is that `this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(` is called multiple time and if you use `this.sub = this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(` previous subscriptions will be overridden by new ones and can't be unsubscribed to because the reference is lost.

Comment: Ok I had rebuild code, you were right this code sux, but this is very old app in dev stage, and now I'am clearing it and adding new features. 
What is proper way for build good valuechanges subscribent under some variable, which I can disable by unsubscribe()? In case [form]="taskForm". Iam asking because now when I declare: 
this.sub = this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe( ... I had no access for unsubscribe() method:( under this.sub

Comment: Hard to tell what is a good place whithout know what "places" your code has. As mentioned. I would put this code immediately after the code that initializes `this.taskCreate`.

Comment: Ok I done like you said, in constructor I leave        
this.sub = this.taskCreate.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            this.formValidator(this.taskCreate);
            this.output = data;
        });

On form open method I added this.sub.unsubscribe(), and after Submit when Validator is called I call sub again:) Thanks again!